# ICU::UnicodeString find the indexOf a code point, not a code unit

Tags: c++, icu, unicode-string

ICU::UnicodeString's IndexOf method(https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/classicu_1_1UnicodeString.html#add90e508b078575eae3d04e596c88dc2) returns the index of the first code unit where it finds the search text. A code point can correspond to two code units in certain cases. I'm more interested in finding the index of the character(which corresponds to a code point) where the search text is found, not the index of the code unit. This is mostly for interoperability with Python3's str.find() method when used with two utf8 strings. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What platform is this on? Windows, where a `wchar_t` is 16 bits wide?

Comment: This is on Linux. A code unit is 16 bits wide and a code point can be 16 or 32 bits wide.

Comment: `std::u16_string::find` should do what you want in that case. It is simple-minded enough not to know about surrogate pairs.